# How to make an interactive program?

Tags: input, functional-programming, ocaml, interactive

I'm learning Ocaml and I need to create a program that can interact with the user in the following way:

```
Program: "Welcome!"
User: command1 arg1 arg2
program: "The answer is..."
User: command2 arg
program: "The answer is..."
User: exit
```

I need a scheme of the loop that make something like that

Comment: StackOverflow is very effective at answering specific questions. But you are asking for more generalized help. Generally speaking you can write a string with `"Printf.printf "string\n%!"` and you can read a line of input with `read_line ()`.

Comment: How i can build the main loop ?

Comment: I'll write up a loop as an answer to your question.

Comment: ocamllex is also a great tool to do things like this : http://courses.softlab.ntua.gr/compilers/2015a/ocamllex-tutorial.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a loop that will read lines of input until it reaches end of file, or sees a line that says "exit".

```
let rec loop () =
    match read_line () with
    | "exit" -> ()
    | s -> Printf.printf "I saw %s\n%!" s; loop ()
    | exception End_of_file -> ()
```

To call this loop in a source file, something like this will work:

```
let () = loop ()
```

To try it out in the toplevel (OCaml REPL):

```
# loop ();;
```

Comment: That was the exact answer i was looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: This very example would be very interesting to have in the [OCaml documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ocaml), since it's a basic thing every OCaml newcomer will want to do. :)